# SQL Query sort and update by row number (SQLFiddle example)

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a sports database where I want to sort the data by a custom field ('Rating') and update the field ('Ranking') with the row number.

I have tried the following code to sort the data by my custom field 'Rating'. It works when I sort it by a normal field, but not with a custom/calculated field. When the sorting has been done, I want it to update the field 'Ranking' with the row number.

Ie the fighter with the highest 'Rating' should have the value '1' as 'Ranking.

```
SELECT id,lastname, wins, Round(((avg(indrating)*13) + (avg(Fightrating)*5) * 20) / 2,2) as Rating,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 'Rating' DESC) AS num
from fighters
JOIN fights ON fights.fighter1 = fighters.id
GROUP BY id
```

The code above isn't sorting the Rating accurately. It sorts by row number, but the highest Rating isn't rated as #1. It seems a bit random.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa1fca/1 (This example is correctly sorted, but I want it to update the "Ranking" column by row number - meaning the highest rated fighter (by 'Rating') gets '1' in the Ranking column, the second highest reated fighter gets '2' in the Ranking column etc).

Also I would like to be able to add WHERE clause in the fighters table (where fighters.organization = 'UFC') for example.

Comment: is it possible to share the schema for the two tables with small dummy data to see the data set

Comment: Sure. Here's a simplified variant of it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa1fca/1

Comment: What is your version of Mysql?

Comment: Just checked. On my website it's 5.6.44-86.0. On my local development environment it says 8.0.16.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() is not available in Mysql 5.6 as far as I know.

Comment: Any suggestion for Mysql 5.6? Need it sorted by Rating DESC and the "Ranking" column should be updated with row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's fix your query so it runs on MySQL < 8.0. This requires doing the computing and sorting in a subquery, then using a variable to compute the rank:

```
select 
    id, 
    rating,
    @rnk := @rnk + 1 ranking
from 
    (select @rnk := 0) r
    cross join (
        select 
            fighter1 id,
            round(((avg(indrating)*13) + (avg(fightrating)*5) * 20) / 2,2) as rating
        from fights
        group by fighter1
        order by rating desc
    ) x
```

Now we use the `update ... join ... set ...` syntax to update the `fighters` table:

```
update fighters f
inner join (
    select 
        id, 
        rating,
        @rnk := @rnk + 1 ranking
    from 
        (select @rnk := 0) r
        cross join (
            select 
                fighter1 id,
                round(((avg(indrating)*13) + (avg(fightrating)*5) * 20) / 2,2) as rating
            from fights
            group by fighter1
            order by rating desc
        ) x
) y on y.id = f.id
set f.ranking = y.ranking;
```

**[Demo in a MySQL 5.6 fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g4MbrhBRBEvFbMbFutepnR/0)** based on the fiddle you provided in the comments.

The select query returns:

```
| id  | rating | ranking |
| --- | ------ | ------- |
| 3   | 219.5  | 1       |
| 4   | 213    | 2       |
| 1   | 169.5  | 3       |
| 2   | 156.5  | 4       |
```

And here is the content of the `fighters` table after the `update`:

```
| id  | lastname   | ranking |
| --- | ---------- | ------- |
| 1   | Gustafsson | 3       |
| 2   | Cyborg     | 4       |
| 3   | Jones      | 1       |
| 4   | Sonnen     | 2       |
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work. :) Where would I add a "where" clause? F.e. I have two columns in the fighters table that I would like to add as a where clause.

Like: "where organization = 'Promoter' and weightclass='Heavyweight'.

So that it only updates the fighters who matches the above where clause.

Comment: @Martin: if I follow you correctly, this would require adding a `join` on `figthes` in the subquery that does the ranking. It was there intially but I removed it since it could not see its use. You should be able to put it back.

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't work. Could you please help me fix it before I green check it?

...code...
             round(((avg(indrating)*13) + (avg(fightrating)*5) * 20) / 2,2) as rating
            from fights
          join fighters ON
            organization = 'PFL'
            group by wfighter
            order by rating desc
        ) x
) y on y.id = f.id
set f.KOL = y.KOL

Comment: Solved it. :) Thanks for your help, GMB!

Comment: Welcome @Martin! It's nice that you were able to add the remaining step by yourself.